# Cannot get @reboot Cron job to run Python script

Tags: python, linux, cron, iceweasel

I have a cron job that loads a Python script on reboot but it will just not work. 
I have checked the Python script and that works fine from CLi.

The .py basically loads a browser to Google and then sends it to full screen. 
(It actually loads another website and enters login details also, but removed for obvious reasons)

Been at this for weeks now and driving me crazy, any ideas?

Raspberry Pi running Raspbian.

- **$crontab -e**

  @reboot DISPLAY=:0 python /prtgboot.py
- **prtgboot.py**

'#'!/usr/bin/env python

```
import commands
import time

webbrowser = "iceweasel"
pgrepcmd = "pgrep %s " % (webbrowser)
process = commands.getoutput(pgrepcmd)

if process == "":
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
        from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
        browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
        actions = ActionChains(browser)
        browser.get('http://google.co.uk')
        elemFullscreen = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html') 
        time.sleep(30)
        elemFullscreen.send_keys (Keys.F11) 
        exit()
else:
        exit()
```

Comment: there are *many* issues with `@reboot` not working consistently - not for root, etc - [this summarizes a few discoveries](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root).

Comment: @Petesh - I have also tried adding to /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
with no luck either. I will add the file now, everything else works apart from the Python script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so Petesh was correct. It was @reboot not working correctly.

Changed the cron to * * * * * so my script runs every minute. Normally bad practice, but already setup script to end if browser already running. Working a treat now.

On a positive note, if the browser crashes it will start again for me :)